# How to serve a 404.html page using FastAPI in case a user goes to the wrong route?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to render the index.html file. Otherwise, return a 404 error page not found.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException 
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI() 

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")  
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def Index(request: Request):
    if status_code=404:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("404.html", {"request": request})
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request}) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a custom 404 Not Found page using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800133/how-to-return-a-custom-404-not-found-page-using-fastapi)

Answer (score 2):

Your `index` endpoint is *only* called when the client accesses the `/` route. So, you can't handle 404 errors in that same endpoint because a 404 means the client accessed some other undefined route.

A 404 is an HTTPException and FastAPI has a built-in handler for HTTPExceptions. But you can override it to provide your own handler. See the [Handling Errors > Override the HTTPException error handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/?h=exceptions#override-the-httpexception-error-handler) section of the FastAPI docs.

Basically, you define a method that handles *all* the `HTTPException`s:

```py
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def my_custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: StarletteHTTPException):
    # Handle HTTPExceptions here
```

The function receives as its 2nd argument an [HTTPException](https://www.starlette.io/exceptions/#httpexception), which has a `status_code` and a `detail` attribute. So you can check the `status_code`, and render appropriate HTML templates. You can even use the passed-in `Request` and `HTTPException` objects for your templates:

```
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def my_custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: StarletteHTTPException):
    # print(exc.status_code, exc.detail)
    if exc.status_code == 404:
        return templates.TemplateResponse('404.html', {'request': request})
    elif exc.status_code == 500:
        return templates.TemplateResponse('500.html', {
            'request': request,
            'detail': exc.detail
        })
    else:
        # Generic error page
        return templates.TemplateResponse('error.html', {
            'request': request,
            'detail': exc.detail
        })
```

Take note again that the function handles *all* HTTPException types, not just your 404. If you just care about overriding the 404 error, you can pass the other errors to FastAPI's built-in handler:

```
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from fastapi.exception_handlers import http_exception_handler

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def my_custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: StarletteHTTPException):
    if exc.status_code == 404:
        return templates.TemplateResponse('404.html', {'request': request})
    else:
        # Just use FastAPI's built-in handler for other errors
        return await http_exception_handler(request, exc)
```