# How to return a custom 404 Not Found page using FastAPI?

Tags: python, exception, http-status-code-404, fastapi, starlette

I am making a rick roll site for Discord and I would like to redirect to the rick roll page on `404` response status codes.

I've tried the following, but didn't work:

```py
 @app.exception_handler(fastapi.HTTPException)
 async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
     ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

A more elegant solution would be to use a custom exception handler, passing the status code of the exception you would like to handle, as shown below:

```py
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException

@app.exception_handler(404)
async def not_found_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return RedirectResponse('https://fastapi.tiangolo.com')
```

or, use the [`exception_handlers`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/41735d2de9afbb2c01541d0f3052c718cb9f4f30/fastapi/applications.py#L65) parameter of the FastAPI class like this:

```py
async def not_found_error(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return RedirectResponse('https://fastapi.tiangolo.com')

exception_handlers = {404: not_found_error}
app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

**Note:** In the examples above, a `RedirectResponse` is returned, as OP asked for redirecting the user. However, you could instead return some custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response) or [`Jinja2 TemplateResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates), as demosntrated in the example below.

### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException


async def not_found_error(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('404.html', {'request': request}, status_code=404)


async def internal_error(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('500.html', {'request': request}, status_code=500)

    
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

exception_handlers = {
    404: not_found_error,
    500: internal_error
}

app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

templates/**404.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Not Found</title>
   <body>
      <h1>Not Found</h1>
      <p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

templates/**500.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Internal Server Error</title>
   <body>
      <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
      <p>The server encountered an internal error or 
         misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

##### Original answer

You would need to create a [`middleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/#create-a-middleware) and check for the `status_code` of the `response`. If it is `404`, then return a [`RedirectResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse). Example:

```py
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

@app.middleware("http")
async def redirect_on_not_found(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        return RedirectResponse("https://fastapi.tiangolo.com")
    else:
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException

# --- Constants --- #

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="./templates")

# --- Error handler --- #

def lost_page(request, exception):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "text/html"}

    if isinstance(exception, HTTPException):
        status_code = exception.status_code
        detail = exception.detail
    elif isinstance(exception, Exception):
        status_code = 500
        detail = "Server Error"
        headers["X-Error-Message"] = exception.__class__.__name__
        headers["X-Error-Line"] = str(exception.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
    else:
        status_code = 500
        detail = f"Server Error\n\nDetails: {exception}"

    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "404.html",
        {"request": request, "status_code": status_code, "detail": detail},
        status_code=status_code,
        headers=headers,
    )


exception_handlers = {num: lost_page for num in range(400, 599)}
app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

This is a snippet I've used across a few projects, it's essentially a catch-all for all 400 and 500 status codes.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException

# --- Constants --- #

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="./templates")
```

This block imports relevant libraries and initializes Jinja2Templates, which allows us to render HTML using FastAPI. [Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/).

Let's dissect

```py
def lost_page(request, exception):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "text/html"}

    if isinstance(exception, HTTPException):
        status_code = exception.status_code
        detail = exception.detail
    elif isinstance(exception, Exception):
        status_code = 500
        detail = "Server Error"
        headers["X-Error-Message"] = exception.__class__.__name__
        headers["X-Error-Line"] = str(exception.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
    else:
        status_code = 500
        detail = f"Server Error\n\nDetails: {exception}"

    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "404.html",
        {"request": request, "status_code": status_code, "detail": detail},
        status_code=status_code,
        headers=headers,
    )
```

FastAPI's exception handler provides two parameters, the request object that caused the exception, and the exception that was raised.

```py
def lost_page(request, exception):
```

^^ Our function takes these two parameters.

```py
headers = {"Content-Type": "text/html"}
```

These are the headers we're going to send back along with the request.

```py
    if isinstance(exception, HTTPException):
        status_code = exception.status_code
        detail = exception.detail

    elif isinstance(exception, Exception):
        status_code = 500
        detail = "Server Error"
        headers["X-Error-Name"] = exception.__class__.__name__

    else:
        status_code = 500
        detail = f"Server Error\n\nDetails: {exception}"
```

If the `exception` parameter is a HTTPException (raised by Starlette/FastAPI), then we're going to set the status_code and detail appropriately. An example of an HTTPException is a 404 error, if you try accessing an endpoint that doesn't exist, a HTTPException is raised and handled automatically by FastAPI.

Then, we check if it's an instance of `Exception`, which is one of Python's in-built exception classes. This covers exceptions such as `ZeroDivisionError`, `FileNotFoundError`, etc. This usually means that it's an issue with our code, such as trying to open a file that doesn't exist, dividing by zero, using an unknown attribute, or something else that raised an exception which wasn't handled inside of the endpoint function.

The `else` block shouldn't trigger in any case, and can be removed, it's just something I keep to appease my conscience.

After the `status_code`, `detail` and headers are set,

```py
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "404.html",
        {"request": request, "status_code": status_code, "detail": detail},
        status_code=status_code,
        headers=headers,
    )
```

We return our 404 template, the TemplateResponse function takes in a few parameters, `"404.html"` being the file we want to return, `{"request": request, "status_code": status_code, "detail": detail}` being the request object and the values for embeds we want to fill (embeds are a way to pass information between jinja2 and Python). Then we define the status code of the response, along with its headers.

[This](https://gist.github.com/TheOnlyWayUp/8da08cd6716062a78cea2d66ffa9c2b3) is a 404 html template I use alongside the error handler.

```py
exception_handlers = {num: lost_page for num in range(400, 599)}
app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

Exception handlers uses dict comprehension to create a dictionary of status codes, and the functions that should be called,

```py
exception_handlers = {400: lost_page, 401: lost_page, 402: lost_page, ...}
```

Is how it'll look after the comprehension, until 599.

FastAPI Allows us to pass this dict as a parameter of the `FastAPI` class,

```py
app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

This tells FastAPI to run the following functions when the endpoint function returns a particular status code.

To conclude, the snippet above and [this](https://gist.github.com/TheOnlyWayUp/8da08cd6716062a78cea2d66ffa9c2b3) error template should help you handle all FastAPI errors in a nice, user-friendly and clean way.