# How to add background tasks when request fails and HTTPException is raised in FastAPI?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, background-task, starlette

I was trying to generate logs when an exception occurs in my FastAPI endpoint using a Background task as:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

def write_notification(message=""):
    with open("log.txt", mode="w") as email_file:
        content = f"{message}"
        email_file.write(content)

@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    if "hello" in email:
        background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, message="helloworld")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="example error")

    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, message="hello world.")
    return {"message": "Notification sent in the background"}
```

However, the logs are not generated because according to the documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#background-tasks) and [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2604#issuecomment-754567166),  a background task runs "only" after the `return` statement is executed.

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: You can try using [Starlette background tasks](https://www.starlette.io/background/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to do this is to [override the `HTTPException` error handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-the-httpexception-error-handler), and since there is no `BackgroundTasks` object in the `exception_handler`, you can add a background task to a response in the way that is described in [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/background/#background-task) ([FastAPI is actually Starlette underneath](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#details-about-the-request-object)).

On a side note, FastAPI will run a background task defined with `async def` directly in the event loop, whereas a background task defined with normal `def` will be  run in a separate thread from an external threadpool that is then `await`ed, as it would otherwise block the event loop. It is the same concept as API endpoints. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details that would help you decide on how to define your background task function.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

app = FastAPI()

def write_notification(message):
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{message}'+'\n')

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    task = BackgroundTask(write_notification, message=exc.detail)
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code, background=task)
 
@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_notification(msg: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    if "hello" in msg:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Something went wrong")

    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, message="Success")
    return {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}
```

If you need to [**add multiple background tasks to a response**](https://www.starlette.io/background/#backgroundtasks), then use:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    tasks.add_task(write_notification, message=exc.detail)
    tasks.add_task(some_other_function, message="some other message")
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code, background=tasks)
```

A variation of the above approach is the following (suggested [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2215#issuecomment-931411005)):

```py
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    response = PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code)
    response.background = BackgroundTask(write_notification, message=exc.detail)
    # to add multiple background tasks use:
    # response.background = tasks  # create `tasks` as shown in the code above
    return response
```

Here are some references that you might also helpful: (1) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) demonstrates how to add [custom exception handlers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers) and (2) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) shows a custom logging system for the incoming requests and outgoing responses.