# FastAPI- customize the 404 error on missing parameter in url

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an API endpoint at `/devices/{id}`. When I call the API without an `id`, I get **404 errors** with the vague message `"Not found"` in the body.

Is there any way to customize the content / message of the 404 error in FastAPI when a parameter (in my case `id`) is not found/missing in the called URL?

```
@app.get("/devices/{id}")
async def get_cellular_data_for_device_id(request: fastapi.Request, id: str):
     print("doing something")
```

404 Error content:

```
 {
    "detail": "Not Found"
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a custom 404 Not Found page using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800133/how-to-return-a-custom-404-not-found-page-using-fastapi)

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804)

Comment: The links point to customizing 404 errors for the entire API, all endpoints, which I do not want to do. The supplied answers are the correct solution to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to determine if the `id` parameter was given, then raise a custom error if not.

```
@app.get("/devices")
@app.get("/devices/{id}")
async def get_cellular_data_for_device_id(request: fastapi.Request, id: Optional[str] = None):
    if id is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Custom Error')

    print("doing something")
```

Note that I'm going off my `flask` knowledge here, so there's a chance this won't work exactly out of the box as I've written it.

Answer (score 0):

One option other than a custom error handler is just simply adding another `@app.get("/devices")` decorator on it, which will return a required field missing. This will cause it to return 422.

```py
@app.get("/devices")
@app.get("/devices/{id}")
async def get_cellular_data_for_device_id(request: fastapi.Request, id: str):
     print("doing something")
```

response when calling devices is

`{"detail": [{"loc": ["query", "id"], "msg": "field required", "type": "value_error.missing"}]}`