# Return User the FastAPI 500 error console output?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a specific case where I actually do want to return any error in the fastAPI function. If there is a 500 error, I don't want to have the error details printed to the console. I want those details to be returned to the user instead of the generic "Internal server error message" how can I do this?
Thanks!

```
@app.exception_handler(ValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, err):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=400, text=str(err))
```

I tried this ^ so far but it doesn't work. I am not using Pydantic models by the way.

I just tried this, doesn't work:

```
@app.exception_handler(500)
async def server_error_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=500,
        content={"detail": str(exc)},
    )
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some ways you can achieve this:

1. you can raise **HttpException** directly and pass there
   **status_code** and **detail**;

> ```
> from fastapi import status
>
> raise HttpException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail="your detail")
> ```

2. you can inherit **HttpException** and pass **status_code**, **detail** and **headers** to the *_*init*_()* if you need your custom exception to be used several times with your unique name - just raise it afterwards;

> ```
> from fastapi import status
>
> class YourCustomException(HttpException):
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
>         self.detail = "your detail"
>         self.headers = None
> ```

3. or you can keep your way with **@app.exception_handler** and return **JSONResponse** with **status_code** and **content** (not **text** as you did).

> ```
> class YourCustomException(Exception):
>     def __init__(self, name: str):
>         self.name = name
>
> @app.exception_handler(YourCustomException)
> async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc: YourCustomException):
>     return JSONResponse(
>         status_code=400,
>         content={"message": str(exc)},
>     )
> ```

and beware of exposing your internals as Rafael Barros mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, the last one works. I didn't realize that content was necessary instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def server_error_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=500,
        content={"detail": str(exc)},
    )
```

It's too broad and I don't recommend it.
Why are you trying to return this to the user? It could expose things you don't want exposed.

Comment: I tried it, that also doesn't work. It doesn't matter in my case how broad it is. It can handle any exception in the endpoint if necessary.

Comment: My bad, this does work. I didn't realize that content was necessary. Thank you!